# Why isn't the evolutionary Turing machine mainstream?

Tags: neural-networks, papers, evolutionary-algorithms

Given that recurrent neural networks are equivalent to a Turing machine, then why isn't the evolutionary Turing machine, e.g. described in the paper [Evolution of evolution: Self-constructing Evolutionary Turing Machine case study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224302029_Evolution_of_evolution_Self-constructing_Evolutionary_Turing_Machine_case_study) (2007), mainstream?